# Can someone explain the concept of continuity and differentiability for functions of several variables?

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity

Can someone explain the concept of continuity and differentiability for functions of several variables? Illustrated examples will definitely help, on how to solve problems(or establish proofs) of the type.

Comment: You'll probably get a much better answer if you add the specific function that you are most likely struggling with...

Answer (score 3):

One of my favorite informal definitions for  continuity is:

> The function $f(x)$ is continuous at the point $x_0$ if it preserves the relation $\approx$. (i.e.  if $x \approx x_0$ then $f(x) \approx f(x_0))$

Here $x$ can be taken as a variable in $n$-dimensional space.

For example, the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is continuous at the point $(x_0,y_0) =(3,4)$, because if $(x,y) \approx (3,4)$ (that is, x is approximately 3 and $y$ is approximately 4) then $f(x,y) \approx 25=f(x_0,y_0)$.